# Distribution of a product of RV's

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be two independent random variables with X
= Unif$(0, 1)$ and the
probability density function of Y being $f_Y (y) = 
\frac{1}{2}y$, where $y \in (0,2)$

(a) Derive the pdf of $U = XY $.

I have some clue of deriving this through the law of total probability but have no idea when it comes to the terminals as it gets me to divide by $0$.

Firstly through the use of the formula $$\int_{s_y}^{}F_{X}(\frac{u}{y})f_{y}(y)dy$$ 
Since the distribution of X is a uniform we can write $F_{X}(\frac{u}{y})=\frac{u}{y}$

we get then $$\Rightarrow \int_{s_y}^{}\bigg(\frac{u}{y}\bigg)\frac{y}{2}dy=\int_{s_y}^{}\bigg(\frac{u}{2}\bigg)dy$$

I assumed that since both of my distibutions are positive i don't have to include the negative portion of the formula. Im not too sure of where to go in terms of calculating the terminals needed.

Comment: Terminology question.  Define the distribution $R(0,1)$.

Comment: Sorry, it is a continuous uniform distribution over the bounds (0,1)

Comment: Perhaps you can show your first few steps.

Comment: Apologies, hope you can follow the latex and the skipping of multiple steps.

Comment: Here is a very similar one: two RVs following Unif(0,1). A 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Uniformly_distributed_independent_random_variables
The steps are: logarithm transform, convolution, transform back.

Answer (score 1):

$P(XY\le z)=\int_0^2P(X\le\frac{z}{y}|Y=y)\frac{y}{2}dy=\int_0^z\frac{y}{2}dy+\int_z^2\frac{z}{y}\frac{y}{2}dy=\frac{z^2}{4}+\frac{z}{2}(2-z)=z-\frac{z^2}{4}$, for $0\le z \le 2$.

Note that $P(X\le \frac{z}{y}|Y=y)=1$ for $z\ge y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes more sense now.